# Accessing string elements confusion

Tags: c, string

I know that string elements are accessed in a fashion similar to other arrays.
i used `printf("%c",str[i]);` to print every character in the string.while using this `printf("%c",str[0]+i)` the code prints  prints out the first character in the string and then cosecutive characters  and stops at the end of string length.

---

I wonder why this happen ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char *str= "string" ;
    int s = strlen(str) ;
    int i ;
    for (i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
      printf("%c",str[i]); //valid
    }
    for (i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
       printf("\n%c",str[0]+i); //not valid
    }
    printf("\nThe length of string : %d\n ",s);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Try `printf("\n%c", *(str + i));`.

Comment: good notation thnxs @pmg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted

```
printf("%c",*(str+i))
```

instead of

```
printf("%c",str[0]+i)
```

When you use `str[0]+i`, `i` is added to `str[0]`. Characters as represented in [the ASCII table](http://www.pinaldave.com/download/ascii_table.jpg) are continuous and adding a number,say 1, to a character,say `'s'`, results in the character `'t'` as `t` comes just after `s` in the ASCII table.

Comment: It's quite true that the ASCII table has no holes. That's a different situation than, say, Windows-1252, which the question asker is more likely to be using.

Comment: Hmmm.. Then, is there a way to check if the encoding used is ASCII? And what makes you think that the OP is more likely to use Windows-1252?

Comment: ASCII is quite rare (particularly on personal computers). Windows-1252 and the like are somewhat common but are being slowing replaced by Unicode/UTF-8 over the last 15 years. Character sets and encodings (code pages) are something you either have to know or guess. There are four points where they are relevant. The compilation source (what the compiler reads), the target (what the compiler writes) and execution, what the OS and user set up (Windows: run `chcp`; Linux: run `locale`) or what the process/thread configures after the OS creates the process.

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet you are not incrementing the array index, rather you are adding integer 'i' to the ASCII value of character at position 'str[0]'. Hence you get the consecutive characters as output.

```
for (i=0;i<s;i++)
{
printf("\n%c",str[0]+i); //not valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the output :

> string
>
> s
>
> t
>
> u
>
> v
>
> w
>
> x
>
> The length of string : 6

The first way is the correct method to print the string. The second way, which you say is invalid, is actually doing this-

Ascii value of s[0] (which is equal to 115) + i

The ascii value of 's' + 1 = ascii value of 't'=116, ascii value of 's'+2= ascii value of 'u' =117 and so on.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0;i<s;i++)
{
printf("\n%c",str[0]+i); //not valid
}
```

What's happening here is:

```
counter    command                output
i=0        print --> 115 + 0      s
i=1        print --> 115 + 1      t
...                               u
...
```

You're adding an integer `i` to ASCII value of `s` using `s[0] + i`, so it prints characters starting from s to the string's length.